# How do I connect to my home's primary wired network through an extra (wireless) router?

Tags: networking, router, home-networking

Thanks for looking!

I have set up a desktop PC in my workshop.  The Cat 5 cable connects from this PC to a wireless router which is connected to my home network.

The Internet connection is working just fine.

However, the "wired" network this is on shows up as a different wired network than the one that the PCs *inside* my house are connected to.  This is a problem because I would like to connect this workshop PC to various shared resources like printers, HD Homerun (cable tv card), shared drives, etc.

When I go to "Network and Sharing" and attempt to find the network that the PCs inside my home are connected to, I don't see it.

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Disable DHCP on the second router, and connect it to the first via LAN ports, not the WAN port.

Comment: @Paul--Worked like a charm.  Thanks!